# Some current alternatives to the old-fashioned "Mark My Words"

Tags: phrase-request, idioms

I thought of using this expression but (un)fortunately I did a quick check to find out that it is old-fashioned. I would like to know some current expressions that convey the same meaning. Below is the definition of the idiom under consideration.

[(You) mark my words](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/mark+my+words).  (old-fashioned)

something that you say when you tell someone about something that you are certain will happen in the future *That girl's going to cause trouble, you mark my words.*

Comment: I'm not sure that *Mark my words* is really old-fashioned, because I can still hear it in many movies and TV series. What really makes me feel old-fashioned is, *Heed my words*.

Comment: *The Day After Tomorrow* is rerunning on my cable again. While watching the scene that our protagonist was trying to warn people that the weather will be worse but nobody listed to him, I thought of this question, and probably if I were him, I might say *Please listen to me!*. Though not having exactly the same meaning as *Mark my words,* I think it fits as a milder and more polite version.

Comment: "Believe you me, ..." is on the rise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mark my words, the phrase isn't all that outdated.

Nevertheless, I tried to think of other alternatives to this phrase, since that's what you asked for. I manage to think of a few:

- Don't say I didn't tell you (along with other variants)
- ...you can bank on it
- You can bet your bottom dollar
- I'm telling you...
- ...I guarantee it

Here are some excerpts where these phrases mean roughly the same thing as *mark my words*:

> **Don’t say I didn’t tell you**: Two years from now, the GOP will officially split into two parties... (from a [news article](http://www.onlinesentinel.com/opinion/COMMENTARY__Don_t_bet_against_a_right-wing_third_party_in_2016_.html?pagenum=full) by Charles Ellison, 2014)
>
> **And you can bank on this**: while crusades may start out as one-man crusades, if the idea behind the enterprise is good, soon you'll have lots of support. (from *Magic of Thinking Big*, David Schwartz, 1987)
>
> We can teach all the right responses in the world but if we never role model them - well, **you can bet your bottom dollar** you won't see them in your children. (from a book on parenting by Eydie Comeaux, 2003)
>
> **I'm telling you**, there's only one way you gonna get to Norlins now, and that's by cab.
> (from *Old Glory: A Voyage Down the Mississippi* by Jonathan Raban, 2011)

You can replace the bolded words with *mark my words*, and the passages will pretty much mean the same thing.

As for the currency of *mark my words*, an Ngram hints that its usage may have peaked about 100 years ago. Yet even in recent years it still dwarfs some of the alternatives I've mentioned:

[image]

I think the most interesting part of that Ngram, though, is the sudden spike in *I guarantee it,* which seems to coincide with Joe Namath's [famous Super Bowl prediction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Bowl_III#.22The_Guarantee.22), further discussed in [this column](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2007/01/29/AR2007012901789.html).

Comment: Your chart stops at 2000. If you extend it to 2010, mark my words is on a resurgence: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mark+my+words%2CI+guarantee+it&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmark%20my%20words%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20guarantee%20it%3B%2Cc0 :)

Comment: @Matt - I'm not completely surprised, but that is still rather remarkable.

Comment: In 2008, "mark my words" is ***[five times](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mark+my+words%2C+you+just+wait+and+see&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2012&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cmark%20my%20words%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmark%20my%20words%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMark%20my%20words%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cyou%20just%20wait%20and%20see%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BYou%20just%20wait%20and%20see%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Byou%20just%20wait%20and%20see%3B%2Cc0)*** as common as "you just wait and see", so how come it's old-fashioned?!

Comment: @learner - Just wait and see – sometimes the "you" gets [left out](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mark+my+words%2Cjust+wait+and+see&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3). As for why one dictionary called it `old-fashioned`, your guess is as good as mine. As others have said here, it doesn't ring antiquated to us.

Comment: @Matt There are often significant changes after 2000--the data is less reliable.  1800-2000 is the most carefully curated set of data in the corpus.

Answer (score 4):

I think I would be most likely to say, "You just wait and see!"

Comment: That's a good one, too.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for this; I hear it a lot while watching cartoons with the kids!

Comment: Or: "you('d) better believe it!"

Answer (score 2):

I disagree -- I think it's not that old-fashioned and a perfectly fine expression that you should feel free to use (speaking from the perspective of American English). You could say "I just know it" or "I'm telling you" to mean roughly the same thing, but I like "mark my words" best.

Comment: (to clarify, it is a LITTLE old-fashioned, more than the alternatives I suggested, but it's not very old-fashioned; nobody would laugh at you if you said it.)

Comment: That's what I wanted to make sure in the first place. Macmillan's and Cambridge's state that it's but Longman's doesn't mention anything about its "currency?!".

Comment: @learner My personal impression is that it's more common in fiction than real life, though I'm not going to research that right now to see if it's correct.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by the phrase ***Please listen to me!*** (while I was watching the movie mentioned in the comment), I can come up with many other common phrases that can be used "when I tell someone about something that I'm certain will happen in the future". In other words, they can replace the part [**you mark my words**] in your example sentence:

> *That girl's going to cause trouble, [**you mark my words**].*

Here are some possibilities I can think of,

- **You listen to me**
  (along with its variations, such as *You must listen to me*, *Please listen to me!*, and so on)
- **You must believe me**
  (along with its variations, such as *Believe me*, *You have to believe me*, *You should believe me*, *You better believe me*, *You'd better believe me*, and so on)
- **Trust me**
  (along with its variations, such as *You have to trust me*, *You better trust me*, and so on)
- **Take my word for it**
  (this one is an idiom, meaning [Believe me](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Take+my+word+for+it).)

Comment: I'd pick "Take my word for it", and "trust me". "Trust me" is super common. The other suggestions aren't as fit as the one I picked.